# how to read Derived field from .assignment group reference field in Service now?

Tags: servicenow

The actual value of the assignment group can be achieved by referring assignment_group.parent.parent.Not sure if I can use Glide Records but I am using Visual Studio 2010 to connect to web service and I am not able to add the required class for GlideRecord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a question about reference fields in ServiceNow, or about using Visual Studio with ServiceNow?

Assignment group isn't a derived field, it's a reference field. Are you asking how to get a derived field off of the sys_user_group table, by dot-walking through the assignment_group field? There isn't any trick to it. What kind of script are you trying to do it with? If it's a client-side script, you might be running into a problem because you can't dot-walk on the client side; you'll need to make a GlideAjax (or, if performance is not a concern, GlideRecord) query to the server.

Please be more clear with your questions in the future. We cannot help if we can't decipher what you're asking.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply..You are right..I understood , this can be achieved  only using Glide Ajax/Glide records..I need help on how I can create a server side script and what that script will contain. I am using Visual studio 2010 to extract data from Service now.I am using service reference option available in dot net .I am adding a service using URL and reading the data from service now into an excel. I am able to achieve this if the scope is one table but if I need to join 2 or more tables, I am helpless..